# Jasper report line chart with two date type axis

Tags: date, jasper-reports, report

[image: Required report]

Hello !

I need to create a report like the attachment shows with Jasper Reports.

I've tried it with line chart. Result  : line chart expects 2 number type field for axises.

I've tried it with Time series. Result : time series expect 1 number and 1 date type field for axises.

I have to use dates, so I need a chart type what can handle dates.

Any suggestion how can I solve this ? I've tried Google at least 10 hour. Now I'm very desperated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've solved my problem. I've written a customizer class :

```
package com.test;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChart;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChartCustomizer;

import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateTickUnit;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;

public class TrendCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer {
public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {
    DateAxis xAxis = new DateAxis();
    DateAxis yAxis = new DateAxis();

    DateTickUnit unit = null; 
    unit = new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnit.MONTH, 6); 

    DateFormat chartFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd"); 

    xAxis.setDateFormatOverride(chartFormatter); 
    xAxis.setTickUnit(unit); 
    yAxis.setDateFormatOverride(chartFormatter); 
    yAxis.setTickUnit(unit); 

    ((XYPlot)chart.getPlot()).setDomainAxis(xAxis);
    ((XYPlot)chart.getPlot()).setRangeAxis(yAxis);
}
}
```